# what is the probability of .text being paged out ?

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system

I am trying to come up with the percentage of times the `.Text` gets paged out of the Memory.

AFAIK , this is not that frequent, assuming we have a large amount of memory.

If you can share some data about it ?

may be `mlockall` system call could help ( Though my experience suggests otherwise ) ?

Comment: Why do you ask? In practice, the hot pages of `.text` segments stay in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for paging is based on numerous parameters, and is operating system specific. In Linux, for example, there is a parameter called swapiness that affects this.

In general, pages are dropped from RAM on a least-recently-used basis. If you have no swap space configured, then .text pages are more likely to get  dropped from RAM, since data pages are likely dirty and cannot be (since there is nowhere to write them).

If you wanted to try to analyze this, you could try an experiment as follows:

Put your programs on one disk, and your data on another. Do not, under any circumstances, put anything but code on the first disk. Now, run your system under the load in question.

Use a utility like sar to gather IO data on the disks as you proceed. If you load a program once and only once, then the IO over time on that first disk should be pretty close to the amount of paging done with respect to text pages.

Compare that to the data IO on the other disk, and you have an approximate answer. Of course, your numbers are going to vary wildly based on your load and kernel parameters.